# ApplicationModule definition class code is blank in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

When i select Generate Application Module class and click OK, The AMImpl.java class is generated without any code. what might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because all the code is in the base class.

What do you expect to be in the class?

When you define to create the class, you can choose what will be created (all based on the time you create the class).

Then all methods you write will end up in this class and can be exposed to the client.

Comment: My expectation is AMImpl.java should have the auto generated code with methods to get the VO's added in the data model. Is it not the default behaviour??

Answer (score 0):

Use is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/adf/develop/extending-business-components-functionality1.htm#ADFFD1025).

Per the docs:

> The base classes of the ADF Business Components framework may be
>   extended to incorporate custom code with all types of components in
>   the framework and to extend the ADF Business Components framework
>   behavior.
>        When used without customization, your business component is completely defined by its XML document and it will be fully functional
>   without custom Java code or even a Java class file for the component.
>   If you have no need to extend the built-in functionality of a
>   component in ADF Business Components, and no need to write any custom
>   code to handle its built-in events, you can use the component in this
>   XML-only fashion. However, when you do extend base classes of the ADF
>   Business Components framework, you can still work with XML documents
>   in JDeveloper.
>        Once you have created framework extension classes, any new business component you create can be based on your customized
>   framework class instead of the base one. And, you can always update
>   the definitions of existing components to use the new framework
>   extension class as well.

Best practice is to create your own set of custom framework extension classes so you have hook points for creating common code for your custom ADF BC EOs and VOs

Comment: My expectation is AMImpl.java should have the auto generated code with methods to get the VO's added in the data model. Is it not the default behaviour??